# Ffmpeg in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use ffmpeg library into Xamarin.iOS app but I can't find any way to get it working. I've made a UWP and Xamarin.Android version of the app using ffmpeg and both are working OK but I'm stuck on iOS...

I only need to execute one command to convert webm audio to mp3, this command is: "ffmpeg -i source.webm -f mp3 target.mp3"

I can't find any bindings to the library and I've tried to do myself following the guidance but It's too difficult to get it working. Is there any easy way to reference the library and execute this simple command?

Comment: There is a discussion here about this, including a possible workaround https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62487/xamarin-ios-ffmpeg-support